# Spring-Data-Rest validator returns 500 rather than 400 status code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring-data-rest on a project, and am looking at introducing validation.

I am able to add my validator manually through extending RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter and overriding configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener to add my validator.

The validation is performed, however I receive a 500 response rather than the expected 400.

The top of the call stack looks like this:

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.rest.core.RepositoryConstraintViolationException: Validation failed] with root cause
org.springframework.data.rest.core.RepositoryConstraintViolationException: Validation failed
at 
org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.validate(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.java:179) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at 
org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.onBeforeCreate(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.java:96) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

It seems as if the RepositoryRestExceptionHandler handleRepositoryConstraintViolationException method isn't picking up the exception for some reason.

I have seen other types of constraints e.g. MongoDB unique index constraints successfully get mapped into a 400 response.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: I have almost the same problem and i created an exception handler  annotated `@ControllerAdvice` and i return a custom response `return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`
The object 'response' is a custom class with fields similar with the response returned by Spring.
https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring